# I am running a python azure devops app it is showing Error /home/vsts/work/1/s\\Conf_Path.json

Tags: python-3.x, azure, cloud, devops

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vsts/work/1/s\Conf_Path.json'
This is the error i am facing while deploying python web app in Azure

[image]

Comment: sorry, given this information its impossible to tell you what is wrong exactly. the path is clearly wrong, but I have no idea how you input it so cant advice on how to fix it